# jQuery each() rewritten?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

I've written a plugin for some `div`s. `textbox` is the class of `div`s and `deactivateTextBox()` is the plugin.

I need to `deactivate` all text boxes on the page. Are the following two pieces of code both doing this? And is the second one more efficient?

1. Code:

   ```
   $(".textbox").each(function(){
       $(this).deactivateTextBox(); 
   });
   ```
2. `$(".textbox").deactivateTextBox();`

Comment: That depends on how the `deactivateTextBox` function is implemented. But the second style should be supported by all properly-written jQuery plugins. (See also: [jQuery implicit and explicit loops](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2013/01/yo-dawg-i-herd-you-like-loops-so-jquery.html) )

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, they both do the same thing.
2. Yes, the second should be more efficient as the former gets all elements, passes the raw DOM element to the loop, and then re-wraps the element with the jQuery object.